# Does margin:0 auto ever work with an absolute div?

Tags: css

Playing around with some absoloute divs I have in my header. logo, search bar etc and trying to get them centered.

Will margin: 0 auto; ever work with an element set as absolute?

I know of some options to center divs within a 100% width such as calc, transform, flex. Are there any more centering 100% options?

Comment: Try to add `left:0;` and `right:0;` and please, post your completed code.

Comment: Hard to work out exactly what you mean, but you may be interested in `box-sizing`: http://learnlayout.com/box-sizing.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work if the element is positioned correctly and has a `width` specified.

In the example below, `left: 0`/`right: 0` is added so that the element is centered relative to the parent. For instance:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can also use a combination of `left: 50%`/`transform: translateX(-50%)` in order to center the element horizontally.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #000;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
```